# Docker content is not rendered in the browser

Tags: docker, docker-container

I am using Ubuntu 22.04.1.

Recently I’ve had the problem that Docker containers that were already working can still be started as usual, but the browser shows a white background.

Only the icon in the browser tab is displayed.

This applies to the following addresses:

```
https://localhost
http://localhost
http://127.0.0.1
https://127.0.0.1
http://127.0.1.1
https://127.0.1.1
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to start a docker-container with phpmyadmin.

The problem i had, was, that the config-inc.php had an error in start

The file start with

> <?
> ?php

Correct ist

> <?php